# Generate a new table out of old one with sorting

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Here is a table where scores are calculated at last row with a formula. How to generate a new table `TotalResults` with 1 and last columns? Can we even sort the last column in the process?

```
#+NAME: ScoreCard
| team | 1st round | 2nd round | total |
|------+-----------+-----------+-------|
| A    |         7 |         9 |    16 |
| B    |         3 |         5 |    8 |
#+TBLFM: $4=vsum($2..$3)
```

Like this one

```
#+NAME: ScoreCard
| team | total |
|------+-------|
| B    |     8 |
| A    |    16 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this function will do the trick

```
(defun generate-a-new-table-out-of-old-one-with-sorting (ref)
  " Inserts an Org table at point copied from an existing table REF.
   only first and last colums are copied and the table is sorted by following the last column    "
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "Table name to proceed :" "ScoreCard")))
  (let ((fline (concat  "|"
                        (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<$<") "|"
                        (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<$>")  "|\n"))
        (fcol (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<<$<..@>$<") )
        (lcol (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<<$>..@>$>"))
        )
    (insert "\n#+TBLNAME: TotalResults\n")
    (insert fline)  
    (seq-mapn (lambda(x y) (insert "|" x "|" y "|\n"))fcol lcol)
    (org-table-goto-line 1)
    (org-table-insert-hline)
    (org-table-analyze)
    (org-table-goto-field "@2$2")
    (org-table-sort-lines nil ?n)
    (orgtbl-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)))
```

You can sort the results in descending order by replacing ?n by ?N in the sort command. For my own that is what i would done.

### PS:

To activate this function, first evaluate it (The simplest is C-x C-e after the last parenthesis, but you can evaluate it in a source block like you did it).

Next evaluate it like any elisp function (the resulting table will be inserted at point)

```
M-x  generate-a-new-table-out-of-old-one-with-sorting
```

Obviously you can change the name of the function for a shorter.

If you find it handy and use it frequently, you can save my code in your init file and (eventually) bind it to some keystrokes.

### ps 2:

If you prefer the code to be evaluated in an org-mode block I had adapted it :

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :var ref="ScoreCard" :results value raw
  (let ((fline (concat  "|"
                        (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<$<") "|"
                        (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<$>")  "|\n"))
        (fcol (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<<$<..@>$<") )
        (lcol (org-table-get-remote-range ref "@<<$>..@>$>"))
        )
    (with-temp-buffer
      (org-mode)
      (insert "\n#+TBLNAME: TotalResults\n")
      (insert fline)  
      (seq-mapn (lambda(x y) (insert "|" x "|" y "|\n"))fcol lcol)
      (org-table-goto-line 1)
      (org-table-insert-hline)
      (org-table-analyze)
      (org-table-goto-field "@2$2")
      (org-table-sort-lines nil ?n)
      (orgtbl-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
      (buffer-string))
    )

#+end_src
```

Comment: I have placed above code in `#+begin_src lisp` tag, but evaluating it doesnt produce the table. Please help this newbie here.

Comment: I added some explain for how to use it. If not enough please ask for more. I can change the code for it to be used in a source block, but that way it can be used only once time. I don't find it so handy.

Comment: I added an elisp block code to do the job the way you first did it.